# WP get page content

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve page content in a javascript function. When I echo the test variable `$htmlblock`, the javascript lightbox works perfectly. But when I echo `$contactinfo`, it opens the page in a new tab.

```
<?php  
    // retireve content from "contact" page
    $contactpageid=85;
    $contactpage = get_page($contactpageid);
    $contactinfo = apply_filters('the_content', $contactpage->post_content);
    //test variable
    $htmlblock = '<strong>Contact Information</strong><br/><table><tr><td id="name"><strong>NAME</strong></td><td id="phone"><a href="tel:+18888888888">888-8888</a></td><td id="email"><a href="mailto:name@email.com" target="_blank">name@email.com</a></td></tr></table>';
?>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openLightbox() {
        lightbox('<?php echo $contactinfo; ?>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You'd need to echo out the content you're creating `<?php echo $contactinfo; ?>`

Comment: Thank you, I made a couple of edits above. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to check the content that `$contactinfo` contains - there might be something in there that's clashing with lightbox.

Comment: It contains all of the html text just fine. But there must be something clashing... Thanks again.

Comment: I'm wondering if it includes too much HTML - are there extra `<div>` tags, or perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, the page contains a table full of links and other html. I copied and pasted the information into the header and used a new variable `$htmlblock2 = '<strong>Contact Information</strong><br/><table><tr><td id="name"><strong>NAME</strong></td><td id="phone"><a href="tel:+18888888888">888-8888</a></td><td id="email"><a href="mailto:name@email.com" target="_blank">name@email.com</a></td></tr></table>';`
And it all works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

`$contactinfo` possibly contains HTML tags, where as `$htmlblock` is just a simple string.

I'm not sure you can do this with that Lightbox. You may want to check with the Lightbox docs (of the version you are using) on how to insert HTML content.

Or, you could try stripping out the HTML.

```
$contactinfo = apply_filters('the_content', strip_tags($contactpage->post_content));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Thanks. I changed the variable to include all of the HTML that is included in within the page contents. `$htmlblock` variable works fine. `$contactinfo` still does not.